# my javascript code not working(debugger not going inside get method)

Tags: c#, jquery, html

1. @{
           ViewBag.Title = "Index";
           Layout = null;
       }

   ```
   <h2>Index</h2>


   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>
   <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
   <title>Country State City Bind </title>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function ()
   {

   //******* code for state bind with countryid…………..

       $("#ddlcountry").change(function () {
           //debugger;
           //$(this).closest('tr').remove();
           var v2 = $(this).val();
           $.get("DropdownTest/StateBind", { country: v2 }, function (data) {
               $("#state").empty();
               var v = "<option>Select</option>";
               $.each(data, function (i, v1) {
                   v += "<option value='" + v1.Value + "'>" + v1.Text + "</option>";
               });
               $("#state").html(v);
           });
       });

   //******* code for city bind with stated……………………

   $("#state").change(function () {
   var v2 = $(this).val();
   $.get("DropdownTest/CityBind", { state: v2 }, function (data) {
   $("#city").empty();
   var v = "<option>Select</option>";
   $.each(data, function (i, v1) {
   v += "<option value='" + v1.Value + "'>" + v1.Text + "</option>";
   });
   $("#city").html(v);
   });
   });
   });
   </script>
   </head>

   <body>
   <div>
   <table>
   <tr><td colspan="2"><font color="Red">Bind Json Result to DropDownlist in MVC4 Country State City Concept</font></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Country Name</td><td>@Html.DropDownList("ddlcountry", "Select" )</td></tr>
   <tr><td>State Name</td><td><select id="state"><option>Select</option></select></td></tr>
   <tr><td>City Name</td><td><select id="city"><option>Select</option></select></td></tr>

   </table>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

   enter code here

   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.Mvc;

   using MVCDropdownlist.Dal;

   namespace MVCDropdownlist.Controllers
   {
       public class DropdownTestController : Controller
       {
           //
           // GET: /DropdownTest/

   ```
       harshalEntities ctx = new Dal.harshalEntities();



       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           ViewBag.ddlcountry = CountryBind();
           return View();

       }

       //code for bind Country Name...........................
       public List<SelectListItem> CountryBind()
       {
           List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
           foreach (var v in ctx.Countries)
           {
               li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = v.CountryName, Value = v.CountryId.ToString() });
           }

           //ViewBag.ddlcountry = li;
           //return View();
           return li;

       }

       //code for bind State Name...........................
       public JsonResult StateBind(string country)
       {

           int id = Convert.ToInt32(country);
           var v = ctx.States.Where(m => m.CountryId == id).Select(m => new { Text = m.StateName, Value = m.StateId });
           return Json(v, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

       }

       //code for bind City Name...........................
       public JsonResult CityBind(string state)
       {

           int id = Convert.ToInt32(state);
           var v = ctx.Cities.Where(m => m.StateId == id).Select(m => new { Text = m.CityName, Value = m.CityId });
           return Json(v, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

       }
   }
   ```

   }

   my function not going inside get method

Comment: Since this is an AJAX get, I recommend you can do some client side debugging - hit F12 in your web browser and interact with your app and notice the changes (including errors from server) in the network tab. Firebug add on in Firefox is very handy in these cases.

Comment: I used firebug but not getting what problem...why state dropdown not fill after select country